# Update Vote of KnowledgeArticle With API

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, knowledge, lightning-knowledge

I have come up with a specific requirement, wherein I need to update the vote(Like/Dislike) of the guest user on the knowledgearticle published in salesforce from any API.

I researched and found that KnowledgeArticleVoteStat is Read Only Object.(Provides the weighted rating for the specified article on a scale of 1 to 5 across all article types. This object is read-only and available in API version 20.0 and later.)

I wanted to understand is there any possible way that we can update the vote count with any custom code or any standard API.

KnowledgeArticleVoteStat Doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticlevotestat.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I didn't get answer from any source or documentation from Salesforce. I have raised a ticket with Salesforce Service Team.

Salesforce Team informed me that Salesforce do not provide the provision to update the upvote and downvote a knowledgearticle with any API.